# Textfield CSS styling using JavaFx

Tags: css, javafx, textfield

I'm trying to style some textfields using JavaFX, but I'm not getting desired results. My goal is to have the textfield be represented by a singular underline. Here's my CSS:

```
.text-field{
   -fx-font-family: "Quicksand";
   -fx-font-size: 18;
   -fx-padding: 1,1,1,1;
   -fx-border-color: grey;
   -fx-border-width: 2;
   -fx-border-radius: 1;
   -fx-border: gone;
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
   -fx-text-fill: grey;
}
```

I have researched this question, but the answers I find to similar ones don't really contain enough information to reproduce and apply properly to my program. It doesn't help that I'm not very knowledgeable about CSS styling. I've tried to use insets with minimal results. Thank you for any answers provided!

Comment: Why didn't you create a minimal runnable example and add it to your question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following works for me:

```css
/* File style.css */

.text-field {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-text-box-border, -fx-background ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0 ;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 ;
}
.text-field:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-background ;
}
```

The following test harness for this

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldStyleTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setHgap(10);
        root.setVgap(5);
        for (int row = 0 ; row < 4; row++) {
            for (int col = 0 ; col < 2; col++) {
                root.add(new TextField(), col, row);
            }
        }
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Thank you, not high enough rep to upvote your post yet. Sorry!

Answer (score 6):

Since you only want an underline, the minimum things you will need are

```
.text-field {
  -fx-border-color: grey;
  -fx-border width: 0 0 1 0; // top, right, bottom, left
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

This will change the border color to grey, set the border width to 0 for everything but the bottom border, and back the textfield's background transparent so it is not white.