# How to apply a single font to all text in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm developing a piece of software which allows you to change the font that it uses for displaying text (when I say text I mean the text inside of Labels, TextArea's, Buttons, etc).

For example, in my program, I have 6 Labels, 4 Buttons and 3 TextArea's along with a Font object:

```
Font myFont = new Font(20);

Label l1 = new Label("text1");
Label l2 = new Label("text2");
Label l3 = new Label("text3");
Label l4 = new Label("text4");
Label l5 = new Label("text5");
Label l6 = new Label("text6");

Button b1 = new Button("button1");
Button b2 = new Button("button2");
Button b3 = new Button("button3");
Button b4 = new Button("button4");

TextArea t1 = new TextArea("text1");
TextArea t2 = new TextArea("text2");
TextArea t3 = new TextArea("text3");
```

How can I apply myFont to every single one of these object without having to write .setFont() for every single one of them?

Comment: this will be useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812588/textfield-css-styling-using-javafx/46813055

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be to apply a style sheet to the Scene where you specify the -fx-font.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typefont

Since the -fx-font attribute is inherited by many classes, you may be able to cover most text by specifying this for the root node.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introinheritance

I find looking at the CSS for the built-in styles is helpful when adjusting styles with CSS:
https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css

https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        String myStyles = """
                         .root {
                           -fx-font: 24 monospace;
                         }
                         """;
        File cssFile = File.createTempFile("demo", "css");
        cssFile.deleteOnExit();
        Files.writeString(cssFile.toPath(), myStyles, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
        String cssURL = cssFile.toURI().toString();

        VBox box = new VBox(4,
                new Label("This is a label."),
                new TextField("This is a text field."),
                new Button("This is a button."));
        box.setPadding(new Insets(4));
        Scene scene = new Scene(box);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(cssURL);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Note, the JavaFX 8 CSS reference https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html is more up-to-date than the JavaFX 2 CSS reference linked in this answer, and the Caspian stylesheet to largely obsolete.  Though, probably, there is no significant difference between the versions which would impact this answer, as the answer is equally applicable to all JavaFX 2+ versions.

Comment: Example code in the answer for a small example stylesheet which demonstrates the application of the concept would also likely be helpful.

Comment: Even without any changes, this a much better answer than the currently accepted answer which suggests hardcoding styles in code.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you add all your `Labels` and `TextFields` to `AnchorPane` (works with other panes too):

```
 AnchorPane mainPane = new AnchorPane();
 mainPane.getChildren().addAll(l1, l2, b1, b2, t1,t2);


 // later in your code you can just call `getChildren` Method of the mainPane and loop 
 // over it and set Font with setStyle() like this:
 
 for (int i = 0; i < mainPane.getChildren().size(); i++) {
    mainPane.getChildren().get(i).setStyle("-fx-font-family: YOUR_FONT_NAME; -fx-font-size: 50;");
 }
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. It’s not good practice to hard-code style in Java code, and this won’t work if you dynamically change the UI at runtime.

Comment: He asked for simple solution with his HARD CODED labels and text fields. If you really want to help, then try to help and give a suggestion. Thanks for down voting my comment always. You are the best :)

Comment: It's not personal, and you shouldn't take it as such. The purpose of up- and down-voting is to promote the questions and answers that are useful to the general programming community and relegate those that are not. This approach would encourage code that's hard to maintain, therefore I downvoted it.